# iOS MapView throws a bunch of valueForUndefinedKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a simple map view in an application with a single point annotation. The code is pretty straightforward:

```
[_mapView removeAnnotations:_mapView.annotations];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@",self.event.address,self.event.city,self.event.state,self.event.zip];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Assume that the first placemark is the correct address (not sure if there's a better way around this, but in theory should only ever match one).
            CLPlacemark *address = [placemarks firstObject];
            // add a marker to the map for the address
            MKPointAnnotation *addressAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            addressAnnotation.coordinate = address.location.coordinate;
            addressAnnotation.title = _event.venue;
            [_mapView addAnnotation:addressAnnotation];
            MKMapPoint venuePoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(address.location.coordinate);
            // get a default map rect
            MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(venuePoint.x, venuePoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
            if (showUser) {
                // zoom map to include address and user if the user has an address
                MKUserLocation *currentUserLocation = [_mapView userLocation];
                if (currentUserLocation && currentUserLocation.location) {
                    MKMapPoint userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(currentUserLocation.location.coordinate);
                    mapRect = MKMapRectUnion(MKMapRectMake(userPoint.x, userPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1), mapRect);
                }
            }
            // zoom map rect out a little so we can see what's going on here as a user
            mapRect = [_mapView mapRectThatFits:mapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
            [_mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapRect animated:YES];
        });
    }];
```

However, when I'm running the app, it throws a bunch of errors that look like this:

```
<MKPinAnnotationView 0x23dadb90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key subtitle.
```

The app doesn't crash, and there's no stack trace, so I have no idea where the error is happening or why. There's nothing called subtitle anywhere near this code, I'm assuming the error has something to do with the annotation subtitle?

Not sure where to look for this - I've commented out the annotation code above and the error goes away, so it's somewhat related to this code.

Comment: What happens if you just comment out this line `[_mapView addAnnotation:addressAnnotation];` does the error still occur? Also, have you implemented the `viewForAnnotation:` method?

Comment: This usually means the class of a xib is not set correctly or outlets are not hooked up right.

Comment: If you share your `viewForAnnotations` code with us we might be able to help

Comment: I haven't implemented `viewForAnnotations`, and there aren't any outlets called subtitle, so it seems unlikely this is an IB issue. I'll step through `addAnnotation:` in a bit to see if that goes anywhere.